# Do x after y increment

Tags: python

I want to do something after `i` is `20`, `40`, etc.

For example:

```
i = 0
while True:
    i+=1
    if i == # increment of 20 (40, 60, 80, etc.):
        # do this
```

Comment: Use `if (i % 20) == 0`

Comment: isn't there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: `if i % 20 == 0:`?

Comment: `for i in range(20, x, 20):` where x is at what value you want to stop (assuming you don't do anything else when the condition isn't true)

Comment: What is inelegant about `if i % 20 == 0`?

Comment: if i % 20 > 0 it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options 1 & 2 uses the modulus operator, to detect when `i` is a multiplication of `20`, are less efficient as unnecessary iterations will happen.

Option 3 uses `range`, and more efficient as only necessary iterations will happen.

***Option 1***

Use `not i % 20`:

```
i = 0
while True:
    i+=1
    if not i % 20:
        print(i)
```

***Option 2***

Use `0 == i % 20`:

```
i = 0
while True:
    i+=1
    if 0 == i % 20:
        print(i)
```

***Option 3 : For Loop***

Using range: start from `20` till `threshold` in jumps of `20`

```
threshold = 10000
for i in range(20, threshold, 20):
    print(i)
```

Comment: `sys.maxsize` huh?

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
while True:
    i+=1
    if i % 20 == 0: # increment of 20 (40, 60, 80, etc.):
        print(i) #or something else
```

Output:

```
20
40
60
80
...
```